# Import accounts on Ethereum Wallet is disabled

Tags: wallets, accounts

The `Import accounts` option in `File` is disabled.
I am using the `Ethereum-Wallet-linux64-0-11-1`, latest version (now).

After I reinstalled the OS, I tried to import some accounts.
I copied the accounts files in `/home/.ethereum/keystore`.

How can I import them?

With the Wallet UI? Where can I see the commands available?

Also the wallet is stuck while synchronizing: "Waiting for blocks...".
Before it was stuck at 8 months ago so I deleted `/home/.ethereum/geth` to restart the synchronizing.
I kept the default Synch mode: Light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If try to open an issue on the github page you can see:

> Mist and Ethereum Wallet are no longer supported applications. Please
> see this [post](https://medium.com/@avsa/da21c8e943d2) for the context
> around this decision and this
> [post](https://medium.com/@omgwtfmarc/mist-migration-patterns-6bcf066ac383)
> for how to migrate to alternative tools.
>
> Thank you for using Mist & Ethereum Wallet!

You can import your accounts here https://www.myetherwallet.com/access-my-wallet.
With the keystore files.

If you want to run your own node I suppose that you have to use geth.